# sending struct to function C++

Tags: c++, function, struct

i have a program that asks for a number of gifts, and then has you input the description, price, and units for it.

i have a function used to display the details here inside it's own cpp file:

```
    void display(const Gift&) {

        cout << "Gift Details:" << endl;
        cout << "Description: " << gifts.g_description << endl;
        cout << "Price: " << gifts.g_price << endl;
        cout << "Units: " << gifts.g_units << endl;
    }
```

and here's where i try to call it through another cpp file:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfGifts; i++) {
        cout << "Gift #" << i << endl;
        display(gifts[i]);
        cout << endl;
    }
```

i can't seem to figure out how to have it display the first, second, third, and fourth values? it only displays the fourth values 4 times. would greatly appreciate some help

Comment: Your `display` function takes a parameter but doesn't use it. Where is it getting `gifts` from? How is this compiling?

Comment: The guessable problem has a high chance of being the actual problem, but the chance that this question will be useful to others is slim to negligible without a [mre].

Comment: How the values are inserted in container of struct?

Comment: @Mannoj `gifts = new Gift[numberOfGifits];` then it's ran through a for loop, calling the input function using `gifting(gifts[i].g_description);` etc. that input function just has a `cin >> gifts.g_description;`

Comment: You have to change to:  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGifts; i++). It is very important that how you are inserting the values into the objects. Above code looks fine to me. You should also share the code around object value insertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void display(const Gift&)` accepts a reference to a `Gift` as a parameter, but without an identifier (a name) for the parameter the function cannot interact with the parameter.

Instead use `void display(const Gift& gift)` and then  use `gift` in place of `gifts` in the function.

Future bug:

Arrays normally are valid between 0 and the array's dimension -1. In

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfGifts; i++)
```

`i` ranges from 1 to `numberOfGifts`.  At the very least this ignores the first, 0th, element of `gifts` and quite possibly will allow the program to access one past the end of the array. Skipping the first value is a waste of memory, but might be OK. Trying to access a value outside of the array is bad and the results very unpredictable.